# Android getusermedia performance issue?

Tags: android, html, performance, google-chrome, getusermedia

I'm using Android device to record audio from chrome browser.
Here is [lib](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) that I used in my app. In desktop chrome recorded audio is fine, but on android it becomes with small sample glitches (less then half a second interrupts). What I tried:

1) record only one channel (didn't help)

2) inrease bufferLen of ScriptProcessorNode from 4096 to 16392 (helped a bit, but interrupts still there)

3) recording with web worker and without (didn't help)

If you have some suggestions please let me know. My suggestion is that browser has some performance issue.